# NMAP Service Information

Tags: python, nmap, port-scanning

With this code I can get the hostname, used protocols, ports and states of the ports. How can I also get the service information?

```
for host in nm.all_hosts():
    print('----------------------------------------------------')
    print('Host : %s (%s)' % (host, nm[host].hostname()))
    print('State : %s' % nm[host].state())

    for proto in nm[host].all_protocols():
        print('----------')
        print('Protocol : %s' % proto)

        lport = list(nm[host][proto].keys())
        lport.sort()
        for port in lport:
            print('port : %s\tstate : %s' % (port, nm[host][proto][port]['state']))
            print('----------')
```

Comment: Can you give us more details, what do you mean by 'service information' ?

Comment: What service is running on that port. Like snmp, http etc.

Comment: @AhmadNourallah 
 
What service is running on that port. Like snmp, http etc.

Comment: OK, so you need to get service name and then get information about it, right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys, I know how its done now! 
Since we use NMAP, nmap can tell us what service is running on what port. 
You can extract the information with something like that for example:

```
print('port : %s\tservice : %s' % (port, nm[host][proto][port]['name']))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get service name by port using `getservbyport` function from `socket` module, try to do something like that:

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getservbyport(80)
'http'
```

There are no clear way to get info (or definition) about specific service in python, so try to search about website do that (and provide API to using it with python).